# PHPStorm Terminal stop working

Tags: php, mysql, terminal, local, phpstorm

When i used PHPStorm terminal, to work with my local database it's sometimes just stopped working, for example i write something - all okay, write some query and it can just stuck and all, i cant write anything else, i see just blinking cursor and can't do anything, can't move them by arrows, cant write some letters else. And after that i need to launch new terminal session and close previous to continue working. I didn't change any color/font settings for terminal, didn't modifyied something in terminal. How can i solve this problem, maybe somebody had same problem, and know how to fix it ?

Comment: What's your PhpStorm version? Also have you tried File | Invalidate caches? Make sure that you don't use network drives for storing settings or project files. How often do you experience it?

Comment: please check [IDEA-119706](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-119706) and [IDEA-115081](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-115081) - does your issue look similar? If yes, please follow these tickets for updates. Steps to repeat and logs (idea.log) are welcome

Comment: after 5 years from this queation,, the issue still exists,
I'm using docker tab to exec bash on a certain container, and they're just keep stopping after few time,
I use linux terminal and this doesn't happen